# Meteor dynamic input fields

Tags: meteor

I'm looking for a way to create dynamic input fields in Meteor.js. I've chosen not to use Aldeed's Autoform for greater control over the code. From front end point of view I have no issues to add dynamic fields with +/- button to add and remove fields. What I'm struggling with is the insert statement on the back end. How can one add dynamic insert in Meteor.js? Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Essentially you need a reactive array of element that's rendered to the DOM via {{#each}} ... {{/each}}. When the array changes the DOM would re-render.

There's no need to create your own reactive array, there's one here with an example that does exactmy what you're asking for:

http://reactivearray.meteor.com/

However I'd recommend going one step further and using the ViewModel package for this (by the same author). Here's an example which shows how to use it to insert fields:

http://viewmodel.meteor.com/#contacts

Tim

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Tim, these are both pretty useful. I'm using Collection 2 so decided to use objects ('object.$'). This is easy solution for me. cheers.

Comment: hey man, how did you solve the issue? I've got stuck with the exactly same issue, I did extensive research, but couldn't come up with working solution just yet.

Comment: sorry, I can't remember how I sorted this out. I think I must have used the answer ^. From what I remember and can make out of the answer above I've used the '$' for dynamic field in the Collection.